# KendoUI-Grid, CustomCommand - enable/disable

Tags: kendo-grid

I wants to enable/disable custom command in kendo-ui grid based on some other column. 
How do i achieve that? Below is sample code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
   {                               
columns.Bound(a => a.Name).Width(90);
columns.Bound(a => a.Flag).Width(170);
columns.Command(commands => commands.Custom("ABC").Text("ABC").Click("ABC")).Title ("ABC").Width(130);
...
}
```

I want to enable/disable ABC command button based on flag value. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Below is the sample code.

```
columns.Bound(a => a.Flag).ClientTemplate(
"# if(Flag == 'Value1') { #" + "<input type='button' 
class='info k-button k-button-    icontext' onclick='clickhere(#=parameter1#)'
value='ClickHere' />" +
"# } else { #" +
"NormalText" +
"# } #").Width(100).Title("ConditionalButton");

//JavaScript

<script type="text/javascript">

function clickhere(parameter1) {                                    
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Event", "Home")' + 
'?parameter1=' +    parameter1;                    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through the command column.

I would suggest you to create template column which displays button based on your condition. How to execute conditional logic inside a template (or use external function to handle for complex logic) is covered [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-have-conditional-logic-in-a-column-client-template?).

Comment: First thanks for answering but I have two more Questions here.     1. I am not binding any column here 2. It should look like button not link.